# matlab returns error

Tags: scripts, matlab

I am running matlab in linux. While running a script in matlab I get the following error. here RayMet_012007.ray_paths is the input located in a custom directory.

```
/bin/bash: line 0: type: RayMet_012007.ray_paths: not found
/bin/bash: line 0: type: RayMet_00.ray_paths: not found
Undefined function or variable 'AD'.
```

I couldn't figure out the problem. The script is working one.
Also the matlab is installed in custom directory.

http://pastebin.com/CRSPpRzm (full script)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the contents of the script and exactly *how* you are running it in matlab (a `system()` command?)

Comment: @meskobalazs: what about lines 94 and 101?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MATLAB code includes the command

```
system('type RayMet_012007.ray_paths RayMet_00.ray_paths>RayMet_012007_new.ray_paths');
```

On Linux platforms, `type` is a shell built-in to determine the *type of* an executable. You are probably thinking of the Windows `type` command, which *prints the contents of* a file - for which the Linux equivalent would be `cat` i.e.

```
system('cat RayMet_012007.ray_paths RayMet_00.ray_paths>RayMet_012007_new.ray_paths');
```